# SQL Alternative for 'OR' in where clause when using outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

I have the following query:

```
select * from
from assignments dah, employees emp 
where 
    dah.person_id=emp.person_id(+)
and 
(dah.effective_end_date between emp.date_from(+) and emp.date_to(+)
and dah.effective_end_date between emp.valid_from(+) and emp.valid_to(+))
or   
(dah.effective_start_date between emp.date_from(+) and emp.date_to(+)
and dah.effective_start_date between emp.valid_from(+) and emp.valid_to(+))
```

I get the following message: 'outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN'. I know about using 2 unions with inner joins is a solution, but I can't use it because I actually have a lot of code (code I provided is just an example).

Edit: i need this done via oracle syntax, because i work with data warehousing and our ETL doesn't fully support explicit syntax. Maybe there is something i am not seeing and this can be written differently?

Edit nr.2 : Maybe date overlapping logic can somehow be implemented without using OR and with oracle syntax?

Comment: You should really learn to use an explicit `LEFT JOIN` instead of the implicit join in the where clause. Even Oracle recommends to stop using the `(+)` syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have to use the old-style outer join syntax, here's one way (simplified, since you didn't supply us with sample data and/or table creation scripts):

```
with assignments as (select 1 assignment_id, 1 person_id, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('03/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual union all
                     select 2 assignment_id, 1 person_id, to_date('02/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('04/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual union all
                     select 3 assignment_id, 1 person_id, to_date('06/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('10/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual union all
                     select 4 assignment_id, 2 person_id, to_date('02/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('03/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual),
       employees as (select 1 person_id, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('03/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual union all
                     select 3 person_id, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('03/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual)
select *
from   assignments dah,
       employees emp
where  dah.person_id = emp.person_id (+)
and    dah.start_date <= emp.end_date (+)
and    dah.end_date >= emp.start_date (+);

ASSIGNMENT_ID  PERSON_ID START_DATE END_DATE   PERSON_ID_1 START_DATE_1 END_DATE_1
------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ------------ ----------
            2          1 02/08/2015 04/08/2015           1 01/08/2015   03/08/2015
            1          1 01/08/2015 03/08/2015           1 01/08/2015   03/08/2015
            3          1 06/08/2015 10/08/2015                                    
            4          2 02/08/2015 03/08/2015
```

Are you sure you got your outer joins the right way round? Are you sure you're not actually after the following instead?:

```
with assignments as (select 1 assignment_id, 1 person_id, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('03/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual union all
                     select 2 assignment_id, 1 person_id, to_date('02/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('04/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual union all
                     select 3 assignment_id, 1 person_id, to_date('06/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('10/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual union all
                     select 4 assignment_id, 2 person_id, to_date('02/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('03/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual),
       employees as (select 1 person_id, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('03/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual union all
                     select 3 person_id, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('03/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual)
select *
from   assignments dah,
       employees emp
where  dah.person_id (+) = emp.person_id
and    dah.start_date (+) <= emp.end_date
and    dah.end_date (+) >= emp.start_date;

ASSIGNMENT_ID  PERSON_ID START_DATE END_DATE   PERSON_ID_1 START_DATE_1 END_DATE_1
------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ------------ ----------
            1          1 01/08/2015 03/08/2015           1 01/08/2015   03/08/2015
            2          1 02/08/2015 04/08/2015           1 01/08/2015   03/08/2015
                                                         3 01/08/2015   03/08/2015
```

Answer (score 5):

Use explicit `left join` syntax:

```
select *
from employees emp left join
     assignments dah 
     on dah.person_id = emp.person_id and
        ((dah.effective_end_date between emp.date_from and emp.date_to and
          dah.effective_end_date between emp.valid_from and emp.valid_to
         ) or
         (dah.effective_start_date between emp.date_from and emp.date_to and
          dah.effective_start_date between emp.valid_from and emp.valid_to
         )
        );
```

A simple rule is never to use a comma in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax.

Note:  Technically, your outer join syntax would have the tables in the *other* order:

```
from assignments dah left join
     employees emp 
     on . . .
```

I swapped them on purpose.  The `left join` keeps all rows in the first table, even those with no matches.  The `+` syntax is harder to follow.  The `+` goes on the side that would get the `NULL` values.  However, to me, this seems less likely that the unmatched rows are in the assignments table.

If you have proper foreign key relationships, then all the assignments should have a correct person.  I may not understand you data, however, and you might want to reverse your tables for what you are really trying to do.

EDIT:

As for *overlaps*, I would be inclined to use the simpler:

```
     on dah.person_id = emp.person_id and
        (dah.effective_end_date >= emp.date_from and
         dah.effective_start_date <= emp.date_to 
        )
```

You can even write this using the archaic `+` notation, if you like.  Also note:  these do not do exactly the same things.  This will detect overlaps where one period is entirely embedded in another period.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to use oracle syntax... date overlapping can be written without using OR? I did some research on the web and didn't find anything.

Comment: @user3014914 . . . I'm not sure what you mean by "Oracle syntax".  Oracle has supported this ANSI standard syntax since version 9i.  Here is a reference on using the "new" syntax from 2002:  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6585774577187.

Comment: About the overlap logic - what about when, for example date_from < effective_start_date and date_to>effective_start_date? I need to gather the data in this case. Date_from can be < then effective_start_date as long as date_to > effective_start_date.

Answer (score 4):

It should work if you translate the deprecated outer join operator (`(+)`) to an explicit outer join:

```
SELECT          *
FROM            assignments dah
LEFT OUTER JOIN employees emp ON
                dah.person_id = emp.person_id AND
                ((dah.effective_end_date BETWEEN emp.date_from AND 
                                                 emp.date_to AND 
                  dah.effective_end_date BETWEEN emp.valid_from AND 
                                                 emp.valid_to) OR
                (dah.effective_start_date BETWEEN emp.date_from AND 
                                                  emp.date_to AND
                 dah.effective_start_date BETWEEN emp.valid_from AND 
                                                  emp.valid_to)
                )
```

Comment: This should probably be a right join.  Plus you have an extra comma.

Answer (score 1):

*Please only use this, if you cannot use ANSI LEFT OUTER JOIN Syntax:*

First: You are missing parenthesis in your query - second aside from the initial JOIN you can rewrite `x between min(+) AND max(+)` as `(min is NULL OR x >= min) AND (max is NULL OR x <= max)`

```
SELECT *
FROM assignments dah, employees emp 
WHERE
    dah.person_id = emp.person_id(+)
AND 
(
      (emp.date_from IS NULL OR dah.effective_start_date >= emp.date_from)
  AND (emp.date_to IS NULL OR dah.effective_start_date <= emp.date_to)
  AND (emp.valid_from IS NULL OR dah.effective_start_date >= emp.valid_from)
  AND (emp.valid_to IS NULL OR dah.effective_start_date <= emp.valid_to)

  OR

      (emp.date_from IS NULL OR dah.effective_end_date >= emp.date_from)
  AND (emp.date_to IS NULL OR dah.effective_end_date <= emp.date_to)
  AND (emp.valid_from IS NULL OR dah.effective_end_date >= emp.valid_from)
  AND (emp.valid_to IS NULL OR dah.effective_end_date <= emp.valid_to)
)
```

I think this selects what you want - a left join with all rows, where start_date or end_date is between the two dates.

You want all rows which either result from a LEFT JOIN with id and right start-date OR rows with the end-date only, without any id to join on... Your query was essentially this: `WHERE ( id1=id2(+) AND ...) OR ( ... )` because AND is stronger binding than OR.

#### If you know that `emp.date_from` and `emp.date_to` are both valid or NULL

So if there is never a case where only date_from is NULL, but date_to is valid you can shorten the statement considerably:

```
SELECT *
FROM assignments dah, employees emp 
WHERE
    dah.person_id = emp.person_id(+)
AND 
(
     emp.date_from IS NULL
  OR dah.effective_start_date BETWEEN emp.date_from AND emp.date_to
     AND dah.effective_start_date BETWEEN emp.valid_from AND emp.valid_to
  OR dah.effective_end_date BETWEEN emp.date_from AND emp.date_to
     AND dah.effective_end_date BETWEEN emp.valid_from AND emp.valid_to
)
```

Comment: Isn't that still going to get ORA-01719?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for your Info - I adjusted it and replaced the additional WHERE-Parts, now it will work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use explicit LEFT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    assignments dah LEFT JOIN 
    employees emp ON dah.person_id=emp.person_id
AND 
(dah.effective_end_date between emp.date_from and emp.date_to
and dah.effective_end_date between emp.valid_from and emp.valid_to)
or   
(dah.effective_start_date between emp.date_from and emp.date_to
and dah.effective_start_date between emp.valid_from and emp.valid_to)
```